# I'm getting an error in my loop. Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException. The error is my scanner?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Ok, it looks like I've ran into a few problems with my main class. It breaks my loop on the 2nd run and displays and error. It says my scanner to read the user selection from the menu is creating the error? How is that, it worked the first loop, but for some reason it can't run again.

```
"action = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();"
```

is generating the error. Does anyone know why this is happening, as it is very important to read the integer the user puts in as the user is selecting a menu option.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.FileWriter; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.String; 
import java.lang.System;  

public class MainActions {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        int action = 0;

        while (action != 6) {

            Contact.menu();

            new Scanner(System.in);

            action = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

            if (action <= 0 || action > 6) {
                System.out.println("Invalid selection. ");
            }

            switch (action) {
            case 1:
                MainActions.addContactInfo();
                break;

            case 2:
                break;

            case 3:
                break;

            case 4:
                break;

            case 5:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addContactInfo() {

        Contact contact;
        contact = new Contact();

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Contact Last Name:");
        String lastname = reader.nextLine();
        contact.setLastName(lastname);
        System.out.println("Enter Contact First Name: ");
        contact.setFirstName(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Contact Street Address: ");
        contact.setHouseAddress(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Contact City: ");
        contact.setCity(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Contact Zip Code: ");
        contact.setZip(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Contact Email: ");
        contact.setEmail(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Contact Phone Number: ");
        contact.setPhone(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter Contact Notes: ");
        contact.setNotes(reader.nextLine());

        if (lastname.trim().equals("")) {
            System.out.println("\nLast name was blank, contact not saved.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            ContactList list;
            list = new ContactList();
            list.add(contact);
            list.save();
            Contact c = contact;
            try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("contactlist.csv", true))) {
                output.printf("%s\r\n", c);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Console:

```
1. Enter a new person
2. Print the contact list
3. Retrieve a person's information by last name
4. Retrieve a person's information by email address
5. Retrieve all people who live in a given zip code
6. Exit
1
Enter Contact Last Name:
asdf
Enter Contact First Name: 
asdf
Enter Contact Street Address: 
asdf
Enter Contact City: 
asdf
Enter Contact Zip Code: 
asdf
Enter Contact Email: 
asdf
Enter Contact Phone Number: 
asdf
Enter Contact Notes: 
asdf

Contact information has been saved.

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at MainActions.main(MainActions.java:33)
1. Enter a new person
2. Print the contact list
3. Retrieve a person's information by last name
4. Retrieve a person's information by email address
5. Retrieve all people who live in a given zip code
6. Exit
```

Comment: check out my answer. It'll solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Scanner(System.in); // Remove this. Not needed.
action = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

Wait up, this is not the problem. Here is the actual problem.

```
reader.close();
```

This line in your `addContactInfo()` is the **culprit**. Remove this and your code will work.

This `reader.close()` closes your `Scanner`(scanning the `System.in`) in your method, as both are scanning `System.in`.

Hope this solves your problem. I just happened to find [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13042008/2024761). Check this out for more detailed explanations.

Docs says this:-

**public void close() throws IOException**

> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated
>   with this stream. The general contract of close is that it closes the
>   input stream. A closed stream cannot perform input operations and
>   cannot be reopened.

Comment: R J is a master in JAVA! this indeed fixed the problem. Thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
new Scanner(System.in);

action = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

With

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

action = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: Nope, same error is thrown. Error line 32 "action = scan.nextInt();"