# Confusin Error with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I keep getting this error and I do not know why :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at Daily.takingData(Daily.java:33)
at Daily.main(Daily.java:20)
```

this is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Daily    
{

    private static int size;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Please enter amount of rows");
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        size = scan1.nextInt();
        scan1.close();

        System.out.println();
        takingData(size);
    }

    public static void takingData(int rows) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Enter 1 To View Number of Markets");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 To View Start and End Dates of Markets");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 To View Start and End Dates of Contracts");
        System.out.println("Enter 4 To View Averages of Markets");
        System.out.println("Enter 0 To Quit Program");
        int choice = 0;
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        choice = scan2.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Got here");
        scan2.close();
        if (choice == 0)
            System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

My Out put is :

```
Enter 1 To View Number of Markets
Enter 2 To View Start and End Dates of Markets
Enter 3 To View Start and End Dates of Contracts
Enter 4 To View Averages of Markets
Enter 0 To Quit Program
(error here)
```

Comment: it is working for me without any error

Comment: I have imported a scanner

Comment: I have closing brackets

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're closing the first instance of `Scanner` here

```
scan1.close();
```

which is closing the associated `InputStream` (`System.in`) - this prevents the second `Scanner` instance of reading from the stream.

Don't close the scanner. Also you could create a single instance of Scanner for reading all  values.

From a design point of view I would move from `static` methods to an `OO` approach with the single `Scanner` instance created in the constructor of `Daily` and all methods becoming instance methods. This will help with testability of the `Object`.

```
public class Daily {

    private final Scanner scanner;

    public Daily() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public int getRows() {

        System.out.println("Please enter amount of rows");
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Daily daily = new Daily();
        int rows = daily.getRows();

        int mainOption = daily.getMainOption(rows);
        switch (mainOption) {
        case 0: // TODO: refactor to use enums
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public int getMainOption(int rows) {
        System.out.println("Enter 1 To View Number of Markets");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 To View Start and End Dates of Markets");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 To View Start and End Dates of Contracts");
        System.out.println("Enter 4 To View Averages of Markets");
        System.out.println("Enter 0 To Quit Program");

        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because you close your scanner right after you  scan:

```
size = scan1.nextInt();
scan1.close();
```

and then try to scan again in `takingData`

remove the `scan1.close();` that is outside of your `takingData`.

When you close a `Scanner`, the `InputStream` that it is scanning from is also closed, in this case your System.in is being closed.

> When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.

Taken from [Scanner javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13042296/1688441 for question:
[java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner reading user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input)

**I am quoting:**

> When you call, sc.close() in first method, it not only closes your
>   scanner but closes your System.in input stream as well. This you can
>   verify by printing its status at very top of the second method as :
>
> ```
> System.out.println(System.in.available());
> ```
>
> So now when you re-instantiate, Scanner in second method, it doesn't find any open
>   System.in stream and hence the exception.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the initial int choice, and try this:

```
int choice = scan2.nextInt();
```

Shouldn't really make a difference, but it could help.