# Java: Handle Scanner input inside a loop with just one Scanner object

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

Is it able for the code bellow to run correctly **without creating a new Scanner object** inside the loop?

Can it be done with just a definition of a Scanner object outside the loop(commented code)?

```
// Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  try{
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("You gave %d\n", x);
  }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Plz give a valid number!");
  }finally{
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want once you get Valid Number then no more asking ? i mean once Valid value getting then want to free from while loop ?

Comment: About closing the Scanner: [java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner reading user input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13042008)

Comment: @vishalgajera No, I just want to give a number, then tell me the number and when the loop starts give new input again!

Answer (score 1):

When you define the `Scanner` outside of the loop, you are using the same scanner on each run of the loop. If the next token is not a valid integer, `sc.nextInt()` will fail and **the scanner will not advance beyond that token**. On the next iteration, `sc.nextInt()` will see the same invalid token and will fail again. Similarly, if you close the scanner, the next iteration of the loop will call `sc.nextInt()` on the closed scanner, which will fail. Subsequent iterations will fail for the same reason.

On the other hand, when the scanner is defined within the loop, each iteration uses a new scanner. Even if `sc.nextInt()` fails, the next iteration will use a fresh scanner that doesn't contain the same invalid token.

Comment: So the only solution is to create a new Scanner all the time? And close it of course? But doesn't that takes a lot of resources, CPU and so on? :(

Comment: @Skemelio No there are other ways to solve this, just read the duplicate question (see the link above your question).