# Java NoSuchElementException with a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, nosuchelementexception

So I'm really new to Java, and I'm making a program for school.  I'm having an issue using the scanner properly.

```
public int[] userShoot(int shotType)
    {
        int[] returnThis = {0,0};
        int hitFlag = 0, shotProb;
        int flag = 1;
        if(shotType != 0)
        {
            while(flag == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Pick a shot");
                System.out.println("1: Field Goal (Normal)");
                System.out.println("2: Three Pointer (Hard)");
                System.out.println("3: Backwards Field Goal (Hard)");
                System.out.println("4: Backwards Three Pointer (Very Hard)");
                System.out.println("5: Trickshot (Completely Random");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                shotType = sc.nextInt();
                sc.close();
                if(shotType >= 1 && shotType <= 5)
                {
                    flag = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = 1;
                    System.out.println("Invalid Response.");
                }
            }
        }
        switch(shotType)
        ....
        returnThis[0] = shotType;
        returnThis[1] = hitFlag;
        return returnThis;
    }
```

With this version of my code, I got a NoSuchElement exception after the first run of the while loop.  So I searched for fixes to this exception, and most answers told me to use hasNextInt().

So I changed my code to have

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
if(sc.HasNextInt())
    shotType = sc.nextInt();
else
    shotType = 0;
```

Now of course the obvious issue here is that if I make shotType = 0, I get an invalid response.  And then it just loops, unable to actually break out of the while loop.  So my question is: how do I properly take multiple inputs in Java through a while loop, such as in this block of code? I don't know how to fix the input getting exhausted through each loop of the code. Do I have to close the scanner outside of the loop?

EDIT: I tried closing outside of the loop like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(flag == 1)
{....}
sc.close();
```

But that didn't fix, it still gave the NoSuchElement exception

EDIT2:

Combining both fixes worked, but didn't give me the behavior that I need.
Code as follows:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(flag == 1)
{
...
    if(sc.hasNextInt())
        shotType = sc.nextInt();
...
}
sc.close();
```

The issue now is that it only keeps the first input, and doesn't allow the user to input each time the while loop, loops.

EDIT3:
Opening and closing my scanner outside of my userShoot method worked.
However, I also had to change the prototype and calls of the method.
IE `userShoot(int shotType, Scanner sc);` as the prototype, and when calling it: `userShoot(shotType, sc);`
Thanks everyone for the help!!

Comment: Yeah, if you close the scanner you can't get anything else from `System.in`.

Comment: Don't keep creating a new Scanner object on System.in. Create it once at the beginning and that's it.

Comment: So if the method shown in the edit doesn't work, how do I properly open the scanner, get input from it inside, the loop, and then close it without having issues?

Comment: Well, I really don't see what could cause this exception but I cannot try out the code right now. Are you sure you're getting this exception exactly *there*?

Comment: Yes, the NoSuchElementException is at the line
`shotType = sc.nextInt();`
This is in the version explained in the edit

Comment: Well, interesting. If I move `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)` and `sc.close()` *outside* of the while-loop the exception does not get thrown. I am not sure why it's getting thrown when inside the while loop.

Comment: Okay, just look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13042296/826983