# Can't Figure out error? (Java)

Tags: java

So I can't seem to figure out the error that the program keeps throwing. it only happens when I select option 2 from my menu and the line of code it directs me to for the error is line 140 which is 
"userChoice = one.nextInt();"

Any ideas on what could be the problem? This is the error code

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at TickerReader.main(TickerReader.java:140)
```

I posted the code on pastebin since it's a longish piece of code 
https://pastebin.com/dqXQhJvN

Comment: Please do your research properly next time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input

Comment: can we see how you are using the scanner object

Answer (score 1):

It's because there are no more ints to read.  You should check `hasNextInt()` first before calling `nextInt()`.

Comment: use the hasNext() function. if(scan.hasNext()) {// read the input }

Comment: If you do that, you need to manually check that the next input was an integer.  (I think you wrote that just as I editted my answer).

Comment: Can the upvoter please learn to read the question? This is obivously not the solution to the problem, just a way to handle a symptom.

Comment: What's wrong with checking `hasNextInt()`?  Unless, by "solution" you mean writing the full working program for OP?

Comment: No, by "solution" I mean to actually fix the issue. But this is not necessary anyway, because this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

When using Scanner's `nextInt()`, it's always best to check first if it `hasNextInt()` first.

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if there are more ints to be read `hasNextInt()` should do it, you could also change your if/else statements for a `switch(userChoice )` statement

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the error by taking

`Scanner two = new Scanner(System.in); 
  two.close();`
And putting them before the if, else if statement.