# Exception in Scanner Input

Tags: java, class, exception, java.util.scanner

The code 
throws these exceptions after being ran while taking an input 
first input works correctly but the second ones throws an exception

[sample output should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrqy1.png)

[program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCoLo.png)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
        at WeatherEngine.WeatherRecord(WeatherEngine.java:53)
        at WeatherProcessingSystem.main(WeatherProcessingSystem.java:36)
    WARNING: process exited with a(n) Unknown (1) error code
```

MAIN METHOD

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice=0;
    boolean flag = true;
    WeatherEngine weather = new WeatherEngine();
    System.out.println("Welcome to Weather Data Processing System!"
            +"\nYou can process weather information using this system.\n"
            +"\nPlease select a feature you wish to use from the following:\n");
    do{
        System.out.println("1. \t Weather Record"
                +"\n2. \t Averages"
                +"\n3. \t Maximums"
                +"\n4. \t Minimums"
                +"\n5. \t Total Precipitation"
                +"\n6. \t Extremes"
                +"\n0. \t Quit");
        do{
            try{
                flag=false;
                choice = scan.nextInt();
                if(choice<0||choice>6)
                    throw new Exception();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Wrong input \n Enter again");
                scan.next();
                flag=true;
            }
        }while(flag);
        flag = true;
        switch(choice){
        case 1:{
            weather.WeatherRecord();
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            weather.Average();
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            weather.Maximum();
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            weather.Minimum();
            break;
        }
        case 5:{
            weather.TotalPrecipitation();
            break;
        }
        case 6:{
            weather.Extremes();
        }
        default:{
            flag = false;
        }
        }
    }while(flag);
}
```

weatherRecord method

```
    public void WeatherRecord(){
    boolean flag=true;
    do{
        try{
            flag=false;
    System.out.println("Enter date in MM/DD/2008");
    String str = scan.next();
    System.out.println(str);
    String [] str2 =str.split("/");
    int a =  Integer.parseInt(str2[0])-1;
    int b = Integer.parseInt(str2[1])-1;    
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        System.out.printf("Loaction: %3s \t\t Date: %2s %2d,2008 \n",wrec[i][a][b].getlocation(),mon[a],(b+1));
        System.out.printf("High Temp: %3d \t\t\t Low Temp: %3d \n",wrec[i][a][b].getHigh(),wrec[i][a][b].getLow());
        System.out.printf("Avg Wind: %3d \t\t\t Max Wind %3d\n",wrec[i][a][b].getWinds(),wrec[i][a][b].getGusts());
        System.out.printf("Precipitaion: %3.2f inches\n \n",wrec[i][a][b].getPrecip());
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Wrong input \n Enter again");
            scan.next();
            flag=true;
        }
        }while(flag);   

    }
```

Comment: Did you create another instance of a `Scanner` inside the `WeatherEngine` class and did `Scanner#close()` by any chance? Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13042296/6396174) if you did.

Comment: i tried creating another instance but that also didn't work and no i didn't closed scanner

Answer (score 0):

```
if (scan.hasNext())
  String str = scan.next();
```

Comment: still the same exception :/

Comment: my bad, that was actually not the issue, but the way you use scanner, every time you call nextXXX() , you need to call hasNext(). I have updated my answer.

Comment: same exception dude

Answer (score 0):

or this, more concise and you should not use exception the way you did.

```
do {
    choice = scan.nextInt();
    flag = choice < 0 || choice > 6
    if (flag)
        System.out.println("Wrong input \n Enter again");
} while(flag);
```