# Scanner Exception error?

Tags: java

The error should not have occurred as I have closed the Scanner object I declared in the `registerN()` function and declared a new one for `setInfo()` to use. But still, I kept getting the following output every time I input `"register"` as the value of `option`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at Student.setInfo(student.java:37)
    at Group.registerN(student.java:87)
    at Manage.main(student.java:168)
```

This is the code,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

// **** Student details ****// 
class Student {
    // Identity description
    String name;
    char sex;
    int age;
    String id;
    // Educational description
    String department;

    void setInfo(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input the following information about the student...");
        System.out.print("Name:\t");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Sex:\t");
        sex = Character.toLowerCase(input.next().charAt(0));
        System.out.print("Age:\t");
        age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Department:\t");
        department = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("ID:\t");
        id = input.nextLine();

        input.close();
    }

}
// **** **** **** **** **** **** //


// **** Collection of the students **** //
class Group {
    ArrayList<Student> DB = new ArrayList<Student>();

    Student temp = new Student();

    void registerN(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many students would you like to register: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        input.close();

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
            temp.setInfo();
            DB.add(temp);
            System.out.println("Student(s) " + i + " out of " + n + " registered.");
        }
    }
}
//**** **** **** **** **** **** //

// **** A class to make use of the objects **** //
class Manage {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Group base = new Group();
        // option string
        String option = "";

        // I specify the options a user can input here

        while(true){
            System.out.print("option: ");
            option = input.nextLine();
            option = option.toLowerCase();

            if(option.equals("register")){
                base.registerN();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("\t\"" + option + "\" not recognized!\n\tReview options list.");
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

I put a breaking point at the point control is passed to the function `base.registerN();` which in turn passes control to `temp.setInfo()`. But immediately after that happens and `setInfo()` prints out `Please input the following information about the student...
Name:`, I get the error I put above. Why is that?

Comment: That's a *lot* of code, most of which I strongly suspect is irrelevant. Please reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: Can you shorten this to a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm sure that's better now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner reading user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input)

Comment: No, it's still not a [mcve]. Do we really need all those options in order to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Jon Skeet thank's for the comment there, I'm not just a "java" beginner but also a "stackoverflow.com" one. How about now?

Comment: Definitely getting there - but I don't think we need three classes here, do we? We don't need 5 different properties for each student, either, or an "option" where we can only type "register". Keep reducing it... (This isn't just an exercise in futility - this is how you should go about diagnosing problems. It's a skill that takes a while to learn, so now is a good time to practise.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below method you have closed input stream by calling `input.close();`

```
void registerN(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many students would you like to register: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        input.close();
```

If you call the method input.close()  ,`System.in` will be closed. It wont accept any further input.

If you want to avoid this, **create a global variable of scanner which can be used by all classes**

`System.in`. was not instantiated by by your code, but by the JVM.

`JVM` will take care of closing it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you dispose of a `Scanner` by calling `close()` you can no longer read from its input stream, even if you construct a new `Scanner` around it. That is why closing the `Scanner` inside `registerN` method leads to an error inside `setInfo` method.

You should change the approach by passing one `Scanner` object around your code, rather than constructing one "on demand" inside `setInfo` method:

```
void setInfo(Scanner input){
    ...
    name = input.nextLine();
    ...
}
```

Also pass `Scanner` to `registerN`:

```
if(option.equals("register")){
    base.registerN(input);
}
```

This way you would use a single `Scanner` created in `main`, and never close it.