# How do I fix a NoSuchElementException from a input file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I was wondering if anyone could help solve this NoSuchElements exception in my program which scans a text very large text and then is added to the ArrayList.

I have tried re-arranging the order of the code to see if that would fix it but now I don't know how to fix it.

---

Exception itself:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at mainTest.main(mainTest.java:11)
```

---

mainTest class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class mainTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> bigBoi = new ArrayList<>(500000);

        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(new File("LargeDataSet.txt"));

        while (scan1.hasNextLine()) {
            scan1.next();
            String data = scan1.next() + " " + scan1.next();
            bigBoi.add(data);
        }

        ArrayList<String> successful = new ArrayList<>(500000);
       }
    }
```

---

The unit of a .txt file : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MWfMKMhSvuopOt9WwquABgYBTt0M4eLA/view?usp=sharing

(sorry for needing you to download it from a google drive, the file is so long I probably would've been reported or something if I had pasted 500,000 lines)

Comment: It would have been more helpful if you shared the exception logs as well.

Comment: Yes it has three strings in each line. First one is an int and the other two are one first name string and one last name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50750997/9020698
I believe LargeDataSet.txt is not there in your classpath. You can try by providing a full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with `scan1.hasNext()` instead of `scan1.hasNextLine()`:

```
while (scan1.hasNext()) {
        scan1.next();
        String data = scan1.next() + " " + scan1.next();
        bigBoi.add(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an empty line at the end of `LargeDataSet.txt` which is valid for `scan1.hasNextLine()` check, but the `scan1.next()` throws `NoSuchElementException` as there's nothing to read.

Changing validation to `scan1.hasNext()` as suggested in the accepted answer, solves that problem, but the program could still crash if there are less than 3 entries on any line and accepts lines with more than 3 entries.

A better practice is to validate all externally supplied data:

```
while (scan1.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan1.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+"); //split by space(s)
    if(tokens.length != 3) { //expect exactly 3 elements on each line
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid line: " + line);
    }
    bigBoi.add(tokens[1] + " " + tokens[2]);
}
```