# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException first trial

Tags: java

I am trying to kick start this coding but facing below error messages:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
>   Analysis.main(Analysis.java:17)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Analysis
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int passes = 0;
    int failures = 0;
    int studentCounter = 0;


    while (studentCounter <= 10)
    {
      System.out.print("Enter result (1 = pass, 2 = fail): ");
      int result = input.nextInt();

      if (result == 1)
        passes = passes + 1;
      else
        failures = failures + 1;

      studentCounter = studentCounter + 1;
    }

    System.out.printf("Passed: %d%nFailed: %d%n", passes, failures);

    if (passes > 8)
      System.out.println("Bonus");
  }
}
```

Can someone please tell me solution?
Thanks.

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: You have most likely configured your environment so that this program is started with a closed standard input (or using an empty file as standard input, which is the same thing). That is very unusual and would normally not happen unless you chose to set everything up outside of the norm. You'll need to describe everything about how you're running your code.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/13042296/8413677

Comment: how to key in the input? I thought the system will only prompt me to key in the input after I run the programme.

Comment: I key in the code at https://www.compilejava.net/

Comment: I key in the code at https://www.compilejava.net/ ,  so does the platform caused to this problem?