# NoSuchElementException problem in java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I use Java eclipse and it shows that there is:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException.
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

It seems that the error occurred at:

```
String city = scin3.next();
```

The console says:

```
java.util.Scanner.throwFor and java.util.Scanner.next.
```

Below is my code:

```
package p1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

class Connection {
private String departure;
private String arrival;

Connection () {};
Connection (String departure, String arrival) {
    this.departure = departure;
    this.arrival = arrival;
}
String getDeparture() {return departure;}
String getArrival() {return arrival;}
}

public class H4_20160235_1 {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ArrayList<Connection> list = new ArrayList<Connection>();
    File file = new File("connection.txt");
    Scanner scin1;
    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
        scin1 = new Scanner(file);
        while (scin1.hasNext()) {
            String departure = scin1.next();
        String arrival = scin1.next();
        Connection c = new Connection(departure, arrival);
        list.add(c);                        
            }
        scin1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("connection.txt not exist!!");
    }

    LinkedList<String> route = new LinkedList<String> ();

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Welcome to Flight Tour NORANG Ballon !!");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("<<< Flight Information >>>");
    for (Connection l: list) {
        System.out.printf("%s -> %s", l.getDeparture(), l.getArrival());
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for (int a=0; a<list.size(); a++) 
        set.add(list.get(a).getDeparture());

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("<<< Cities in the DB >>>");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    for (String city: set) { 
        System.out.printf("%s", city);
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Let's plan a round-trip route!");
    Scanner scin2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the starting city : ");
    String departure = scin2.next();
    scin2.close();
    route.add(departure);
    System.out.printf("From %s you can fly directly to :", departure);
    System.out.println("\n");

    ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<String> ();
    for (Connection l : list) {
        if (departure.equals(l.getDeparture())) {
            cities.add(l.getArrival());
            System.out.println(l.getArrival());
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        Scanner scin3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Where do you want to go from %s?", route.get(i));
        String city = scin3.next();
        scin3.close(); 
        i++;
        if (cities.contains(city) == false)
            System.out.println("***** You can't get to that city by a direct flight. *****");
        if (route.contains(city) == true) 
            break;
        ArrayList<String> cities2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Connection l: list) {
            if (city.equals(l.getDeparture())) {
                cities2.add(l.getArrival());
                System.out.println(l.getArrival());
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("=====================================");
    System.out.println("<<<  Your Final Route  >>>");
    Iterator <String>iter = route.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String temp = (String)iter.next();
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Have a nice Trip with NORANG Ballon ~");                       
}
```

}

And below is my connection.txt file.

```
SanJose SanFrancisco 
SanJose Anchorage 
NewYork Anchorage 
NewYork SanJose 
NewYork SanFrancisco 
NewYork Honolulu 
Anchorage NewYork 
Anchorage SanJose 
Honolulu NewYork 
Honolulu SanFrancisco 
Denver SanJose 
SanFrancisco NewYork
SanFrancisco Honolulu 
SanFrancisco Denver
```

Comment: why are you open and close scanner input in a while and just not open it outside for one time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner reading user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input)

Answer (score 0):

You must check there is a new token to get, with [hasNext()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext--) method, before each call to the [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) method.

Like you can see in the documentation of [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) method:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
> complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
> delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to
> scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true. [...]
>
> NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available

And specifically stated in the [hasNext()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext--) method:

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not
> advance past any input.

In addition, to improve your source code, you should instantiate your Scanner once for all, outside your loop.