# Java Scanner run time error java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

I wrote a java code, using a few method who use Scanner. the first Method worked well, but the second got stack with the error

> "java.util.NoSuchElementException".

The code of the first method **maxPile**:

```
 public static int maxPile() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter max number of piles");
    int pMax = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();
    return pMax;
}
```

the code of the second method **maxMatches** :

```
public static int maxMatches() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter max number of matches per pile");
    int mMax = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();
    return mMax;
}
```

The methods are identical, but the first worked, the second not...
my output -

```
enter max number of piles
8
enter max number of matches per pile
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at autoNim.autoNim.maxMatches(autoNim.java:89)
at autoNim.autoNim.main(autoNim.java:12)
```

(the '8' is my input, line 12 call the method MaxMatches, line 89 is `xint mMax=scan.nextInt();` from the method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

It is because you closed the scanner. Closing a scanner always closes the underlying resource, i.e. `System.in`. You can not use `System.in` anymore after you closed it.

**Do not close** scanners tied to `System.in`.

Resources should only be closed by the one who opened them. The JVM opened `System.in` and it will also close it again when your program finishes. You are not responsible for managing `System.in`, keep it open.

---

### Exception-safe closing

Note that if you want to close a scanner, you must make sure that it is exception-safe. I.e. you need to wrap it with *try-catch-finally*. If possible, prefer to use *try-with-resources*:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(...)) {
    ...
}
```

Which will auto-close it in an exception-safe manner after the *try-block*.

Comment: However it's not recommended to use multiple **Scanner** instances tied with **System.in**

There are side effects in defining multiple scanners in your program. You can find detailed explanation on below link:
(https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/FIO06-J.+Do+not+create+multiple+buffered+wrappers+on+a+single+byte+or+character+stream)