# How do I get while input (except when the user inputs 0 that terminates the program) in Java?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I want to get loop input except when the user inputs 0 that terminates the program in Java. I know how to implement this in C++ (as shown below), but the Java code I wrote doesn't work.

C++:

```cpp
while (cin >> n, n) {
    GraphAdjList G;
    CreateAdjListGraph(G, n);
    n = 0;
}
```

Java:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
n = sc.nextInt();
while (n != 0) {
    Graph G = new Graph();
    G.CreateAdjListGraph(n);
    //G.print();
    n = sc.nextInt();
}
```

This is what I want. The program terminates only when the user inputs 0.

```
2
qRj dIm
aTy oFu
4
qRj aTy
qRj oFu
oFu cLq
aTy qUr
0
```

Comment: Define "didn't work". What are yo doing **precisely**, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: it throws Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: I cannot continue to input more "n" in this program

Comment: You're probably closing System.in somewhere inside CreateAdjListGraph. What are you typing? What does this method do?

Comment: The Problem seems to be somewhere inside CreateAdjListGraph(n);

Comment: This a Graph problem. the n indicate this graph has n edges, in CreateAdjListGraph() method, the user input n sets of edges like"A B"\n "A C",than I put this edges in my class and create a digraph. I use another Scanner in this method and closed it when I'm done. In this method I deleted all print statement but the problem remains

Comment: @superman22 Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also include the full exception message you get. And please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextInt()` won't work for your case, If your input contains a non-integer word it throws `InputMismatchException`. You better use `nextLine()` and try to convert each word in to `int` with `Integer.parseInt`.

For example:

```java
        int n = -1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line;

        while (n != 0){
            line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] splits = line.split(" ");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splits));

            for (String split : splits) {
                try {
                    n = Integer.parseInt(split);
                    if (n == 0)
                        break;
                    //Graph G = new Graph();
                    //G.CreateAdjListGraph(n);

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // handling
                }
            }
        }
```

This should work even if you give all inputs in the same line.

Comment: thank you! But it didn't work either. it throws  java.util.NoSuchElementException I think it's because it the while loop I used println and the Scanner receive the newline  rather than waiting for my input

Comment: Added an example. Check now.

Comment: Thank you！I found My Bug, it's because i used another Scanner in a method and turn it down. Now I know that you only need to close scanner once.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `scan.nextInt()` because in your sample program run you took some `non-inetger values` as input, so, in that case you code will fail.

Use `scan.nextLine()` this will take argument as `String` and not as `Integer`. Now you can change compare the results for your `While loop`.

Working Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class stackScanner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.nextLine();

        // as you are now taking "String" from user so you have to compare it with "0" not 0
        while(!(input.equals("0")))  // while input is not 0
        {
            // your code here
            input = scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I am using `String.equals()` and not `==` operator, reasons:

- As `String.equals()` always return `boolean value` it doesn't through any exception.
- We can use `==` operators for **reference comparison** (address comparison) and `Stinrg.equals()` method for **content comparison**. In simple words, `==` checks if both objects point to the same memory location whereas `String.equals()` evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects.

[For more on String.equals()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/)

Comment: Thank you! But i am so sorry that I didn't write clearly in my question. when I want user to type a int, there is only this int on the currently line. It's more like this 3\n A B\n C D\n C B\n 0\n and the program terminates

Comment: where \n means the following is on a newline

Comment: I don't understand actually what you want to do with this code? You want to take input as long as user inputs "0", then your while-loop should terminate. My code is exactly doing this. However, a little more information is required so that I can solve your problem.

Comment: This a Graph problem. the n indicate this graph has n edges, in CreateAdjListGraph() method, the user input n sets of edges like"A B"\n "A C",than I put this edges in my class and create a digraph. I use another Scanner in this method and closed it when I'm done. In this method I deleted all print statement but the problem remains

Comment: It's an Online Judge title. It wants this way to check more samples during one inputs. I thought this is an popular way when coding in OJ

Comment: There is still some ambiguity on how you are achieving this. See this, you are using `CreateAdjListGraph(n)` to add the edge, then you should only take one `String` input at a time with out any `space` between them. As you are saving the input in `n`. What I think your input should be like "A\n B\n E\n R\n" and not like this "A B"\n "A C.