# Gradle run task throws java.util.NoSuchElementException when trying to use System.in

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, exception

I've been smashing my head against the wall all night. So I have a build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    java

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application.
    application
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre")

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")

    // Use Google Protocol Buffers
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.11.0")
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClassName = "carnival.EntryPoint"
}
```

When I try to get user input from the terminal with `new Scanner(System.in)`, I'm given this:

```
> Task :run FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
        at carnival.App.run(App.java:56)
        at carnival.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:9)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

So I try to make my own run task:

```
/// ...
// removed application plugin

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDir("src/main/java")
    }
}

tasks.register<JavaExec>("run") {
    main = "carnival.EntryPoint"
    standardInput = System.`in`
}
```

But apparently I'm not setting the source directory correctly because I get the following:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class carnival.EntryPoint
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: carnival.EntryPoint
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your issue is potentially not related to Gradle at all. Did you check [java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner reading user input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13042008/5006866)?

Comment: Yeah I saw this and I'm creating a Scanner basically from the start of the application without closing any previous Scanners.

Comment: consider posting relavant application code where this issue occurs.