# I've been doing for java server and client, is there any way stop avoid this kind of error and start the menu again?

Tags: java, server

> ```
> =========Menu Bagian Server=========
> 1. Start Server
> 2. server room
> 2. Exit
> =============================================
> Masukkan Pilihan: masukkan angka! 
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>   at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
>   at com.company.Server.menuServer(Server.java:35)
> ```
>
> at com.company.Server.main(Server.java:17)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

here is the code, how to make the menu loop again so i can start the server after it terminated

```
public static void serverRoom() throws IOException{
   din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
   dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        String str = "", str2;
        while (!str.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
            str = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("client says: " + str);
            str2 = br.readLine();
            dout.writeUTF(str2);
            dout.flush();
        }
        din.close();
        s.close();
        ss.close();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner reading user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader` are so-called filter streams: They don't themselves represent a resource that must be closed; they wrap around some other resource.

The rule is, if you close a filterstream, it closes the thing they wrapped. (So, calling `close()` on `br` will cause that bufferedreader to invoke `close()` on that `new InputStreamReader` object, which in turn causes it to call `close` on `System.in`.

Here's the thing, while usually you want to always close resources, **you do not want to close `System.in`!**

You are, here, by using the try construct.

Solution: Just.. do not do that. Do not make a `try() {}` block here.

Your IDE might complain. Tell it to shut up, it is wrong.

You get this error because the code closes `System.in` (by reaching the end of the try-with-resources block, which invokes `close()` on the resource, which invokes `close()` on the ISR, which invokes `close()` on `System.in`), and once it is closed, no further lines can be read from it.