# My code contains a scanner but refuses to go past the first line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      {  try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) { 

  while (true) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers to peform operations");
    System.out.println("Enter the first number");
    int x = sc.nextInt();
```

/This is where my code stops^. I just need to see the error thats here because I can't see it.

Comment: What do you mean it stops? What's after that? Could it just be that it's looping and waiting for input again?

Comment: Now this isn't the end of the code but I just had to cut most of it off to be able to post.

Comment: Did you enter a number into your console and confirm it by pressing enter?

Comment: Do not try with resources with a scanner on System.in it closes System.in

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yeah I get an error after it prints "Enter the first number". It says "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:10)"

Comment: I didn't get to do that because it gave me an error @maloomeister

Comment: @MarkAshibuogwu Like Jens says, we need to see a minimal reproducible example, because that code **by itself** (and assuming you just close the loop and the `try` after reading) shouldn't throw that exception)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input

Comment: What comes after it is this:

System.out.println("Enter the first number");
int x = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter the second number");
int y = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Choose the operation you want to peform");
System.out.println("Choose 1 for ADDITION");
System.out.println("Choose 2 for SUBTRACTION");
System.out.println("Choose 3 for MULTIPLICATION");
System.out.println("Choose 4 for DIVISION");
System.out.println("Choose 5 for MODULUS");
System.out.println("Choose 6 for EXIT");

int n = sc.nextInt ();
switch (n) {

After that I just have the switch cases.

Comment: Really sorry if I'm a bit messy right now. I'm new to Stack Overflow

Comment: Oh you mean the "try" loop I put in. Ok I think I know what to do now thanks. @Jens

Comment: @MarkAshibuogwu for future reference, that code should have gone in the question (using the [edit] link) and not in the comments.

Comment: there is no `try`-loop

Comment: @Jens there's only `do`-loop or `do not`-loop?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca sorry can not get you

Comment: @Jens it was a Star Wars joke (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQ4yd2W50No)