# Using a Scanner object in a while loop for a menu gives a NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I'm creating a simple main menu for my program which asks for users to input an integer between 1 and 6, does the corresponding option using a switch statement and then should loop back to the main menu (unless the user chose to exit). However, I keep getting a NoSuchElementException when the program loops back to the beginning after displaying the options, without letting me input another option.

I've searched online for answers and none of them have seemed to work for me. Most answers talk about the input stream needing to be cleared and using `input.nextLine()` after `input.nextInt`, which seemed to have fixed the problem for others. Or just using `input.nextLine()` and converting it into an integer. Both of these have not worked for me.

Here's my code:

```
public static void displayMainMenu() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = 0;

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Bike Registry");
            System.out.println("\nMain Menu");
            System.out.println("1. List All Bikes");
            System.out.println("2. Add a New Bike");
            System.out.println("3. Delete a Bike");
            System.out.println("4. Change a Bike Attribute");
            System.out.println("5. DEBUG: Dump objects (toString)");
            System.out.println("6. Exit");
            
            option = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine(); 

            switch(option) {
                case 1:
                    displayAllBikes();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    addNewBike();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    deleteBike();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    alterBike();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    dumpBikes();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("This is not a valid option! Please select from the menu!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
        at ca.sfu.cmpt213.Bike.BikeMethods.displayMainMenu(BikeMethods.java:21)
        at ca.sfu.cmpt213.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Comment: Are you closing a Scanner instance somewhere else in your code, an instance that is based on System.in? If you do this, then the System.in stream is closed and cannot be re-opened and this exception will be thrown. The solution is to not close this type of Scanner, and also to not re-create an instance, but rather to share the same instance to where it is needed. Please see this question: [java.util.NoSuchElementException - Scanner reading user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input), for more on this.

Comment: We'll need to see the code you haven't shown us, and also please show us what input you give the program, and its full output

Comment: Yes, that's got to be the problem as you're not seeing an IllegalStateException nor an InputMismatchException. You are closing a Scanner instance based on System.in before calling this method. The solution is: don't do this. Again, create a single Scanner instance based on System.in that is used throughout the program, and pass it to where it is needed, such as via a method argument.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This was the problem! I had created a new Scanner object in the addNewBike() method and closed it at the end, which was the method I was using to test the menu. Thank you, I had completely ignored that as a point of error!

Comment: You're welcome, but having said that, you will want to improve your Google search skills on this. You must have been searching on Scanner problems but seem to have left out the text "NoSuchElementException" from your searches, and that is the key. In the future, you will *always* want to search on the specific exception type.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Definitely noted!